# How to remove border for specified cells in Excel using conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a simple requirement where border between specified cells needs to be removed by using conditional formatting. Please refer below image. I was able to change the background color and calculate percentage using this below formula. But border needs to be removed between these two columns only on % rows. 
Any help/ideas would be really appreciated.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Growth",$A1))
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Format... for the same rule as applies the grey-green fill (Manage Rules..., Edit Rule...) go to Border and remove (click as required) the left-hand border for the box that contains `Text`.

Comment: I have tried that it doesn't seems to be working. I have attached that image to the question.

Comment: Got it! By removing left- handed border from the second( greenish ) rule. Thank you.